# A lot of get slugs - is there a way to shorten the code?

Tags: symfony

I have a lot of get variables that I have to pass in twig templates, like:

```
{{ path('route_name', {'slug1' => a, 'slug2' => b, 'slug3' => c, 'slug4' => d, 'slug5' => 'changed'}) }}
```

While only one slug was changed here. I was thinking about creating the array of all get variables in the controller and passing it to twig template. The just overriding the slug that was changed, something like:

```
{{ path('route_name', get_variables, {'slug5' => 'changed'}) }}
```

But it doesn't work of course. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ParamConverter annotation could help you :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html